# 3rd Party x86 Library on M1 via rosetta?

Tags: java, linux, apple-m1, lib, rosetta

I have a java application that loads a third-party library. This is a native library that is wrapped in a java package and has an underlying windows and linux implementation.

I have an M1 mac and an Intel mac and I've managed to successfully get the application running on the Intel mac using a linux distro running in VMware.

However, I've been not so successful in doing this on the M1 mac. The java application will build and run but fails when calling the 3rd party library. Also, the x86-64 linux distro won't run in vmware on the m1 - I tried the m1 tech preview and intel on rosetta.

Looking for ideas on how I might if possible solve this.

Comment: Did you ask the provider of the third part library for a version for the m1 achictecture? "Also, the x86-64 linux distro won't run in vmware on the m1 - I tried the m1 tech preview and intel on rosetta." This seems like a totally separate problem that you should ask the vmware provider and the linux distrobution.

Comment: I haven't but I'm pretty sure they won't invest the time in it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using UTM to emulate x86-64 distros. I haven't faced any problems. There are different options [here](https://nomadic-dmitry.medium.com/apple-silicon-m1-how-to-run-x86-and-arm-virtual-machines-on-it-cdd9d9054483). I think you can figure it out using UTM. It is an emulation and virtualization solution. This allows us to either run native ARM VMs or execute Intel x86 Virtual Machines by using emulation.